# Visual Studio 2015 build event variables

Tags: visual-studio, variables, post-build-event

I want to use some simple variables in the Post-Build event. But I am getting some strangeness. I can't tell if this is a VS bug or I am doing something wrong.

Can anyone please tell me why I can't use %debug% or %aa% ? See the Evaluated Value area to see how VS 2015 is treating these variables.

[image]

Comment: Looks like it url-encodes `%de` to `Þ` (and %aa accordingly).

Comment: Thanks. I managed to find the answer: From MS: Because the '%' character is reserved by MSBuild, if you specify an environment variable replace each % escape character with the %25 hexadecimal escape sequence. For example, replace %WINDIR% with %25WINDIR%25. MSBuild replaces each %25 sequence with the % character before it accesses the environment variable.